# Add a loading graphic jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jquery ajax api so load in some content, the code looks like this,

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"/search/location",
   data: getQuery,
   success:function(data){
       //alert(getQuery);
       //console.log(data);
       $('body.secEmp').html(data); //overwrite current data
       setUpRegionCheckBoxes(); //fire function again to reload DOM
   }
```

});

In my HTML i have `<div id="loading">Loading Content</div>` this is has a css style on it of `display:none`, while my ajax is bring in the content I want to show the div that is hidden, but I cant find a away too have tried attaching `.ajaxStart` on my loading div then doing `show()` but that did not work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#loading").show(); // show the div before the ajax call

$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"/search/location",
   data: getQuery,
   success:function(data){
       //alert(getQuery);
       //console.log(data);
       $('body.secEmp').html(data); //overwrite current data
       setUpRegionCheckBoxes(); //fire function again to reload DOM

       $("#loading").hide(); //hide the loading div in callback function
   },
   error: function(){
       // error callback routine
       $("#loading").hide(); //hide the loading div in callback function
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
$("#loading").show();
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"/search/location",
   data: getQuery,
   success:function(data){
       //alert(getQuery);
       //console.log(data);
       $('body.secEmp').html(data); //overwrite current data
       setUpRegionCheckBoxes(); //fire function again to reload DOM
       $("#loading").hide();
   }
});
```

You may also want to hide the div in case of an error. You can also experiment with fadeIn and fadeOut for some nice effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#loading").show();
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"/search/location",
   data: getQuery,
   success:function(data){
       //alert(getQuery);
       //console.log(data);
       $('body.secEmp').html(data); //overwrite current data
       setUpRegionCheckBoxes(); //fire function again to reload DOM
       $("#loading").fadeOut();
   }
});
```

You've to put  `$("#loading").hide();` in you're script asswell for not showing the loading div when AJAX is not triggerd

//EDIT

ah nevermind you got in your style `display: none;`